# Разнотолкования

Tags: егэ, смысл

При выполнении ЕГЭ-теста встретилось такое задание: *Укажите в предложениях [тут номера предложений] слово, употребленное в значении "монарх, его семья и придворные"*. Во всех указанных предложениях единственным подходящим хоть как-то вариантом было слово *фрейлина*. Учитель, настаивая на таком ответе, объясняла, что фрейлина относится к придворным, однако ученик, несогласный с преподавателем, отмечал, что, хотя фрейлина и придворная дама, она не монарх, и не его семья, и далеко не все придворные (фрейлины - именно дамы). Учитель же говорил, мол, нужно выбрать такое слово, которое подходит под какое-то одно значение, то есть не обязательно, чтобы слово значило все и сразу. Ученик, естественно, не согласился: ведь в формулировке вопроса (она приведена выше) четко написано, даже взято в кавычки (как раз все и сразу, вместе, неделимо) значение.

Можно ли действительно считать, что в задании имеется в виду "найти слово, которое подходит хотя бы под одно из значений (то есть либо монарх, либо его семья, либо придворные)", или же здесь возможна только одна трактовка: нужно найти слово, подходящее по значению "монарх, его семья и придворные"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правильно ученик не согласился, трактовка одна -"монарх, его семья и придворные". И наверняка где-нибудь это слово есть, например, "двор". Нужно было дать эти предложения, мы бы нашли искомое слово, не гадали бы.

Comment: Да вот по памяти пришлось восстанавливать. Я бы, конечно, дал предложения: была бы возможность... Кстати, может и *двор*. Спасибо!